# Session lost after Response.Redirect

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I need your help.

**Where do I start to I can find out what is wrong with my configurations?**

On my development machine, when I use "View in Browser" in Visual Studio 2015, my code retains session values.

However, when I switch user (another user account on my Windows machine) and use Visual Studio to view the same page, session values are lost across page redirects. I also tried my code on my friend's development machine and session values are also lost too.

Is this due to IIS Express configuration? Could the IIS Express Application Pool be running out of memory and recycling the pool - causing the session to be reset? Or could this be due to IIS Express version 32bit/64bit on a 64bit machine?

Here is my sample code to test this behavior:

**SessionRedirect.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="SessionRedirect.aspx.vb" Inherits="Sandbox_SessionRedirect" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <p>
            A: <% Response.Write(Session("A")) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            B: <% Response.Write(Session("B")) %>
        </p>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Go" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**SessionRedirect.aspx.vb**

```
Partial Class Sandbox_SessionRedirect
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub Sandbox_SessionRedirect_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Session("A") = "A"
        Session("B") = "B"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Session("B") = "bounce"
        Page.Response.Redirect("SessionRedirect2.aspx", False)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**SessionRedirect2.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="SessionRedirect2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Sandbox_SessionRedirect2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <p>
                A: <% Response.Write(Session("A")) %>
            </p>
            <p>
                B: <% Response.Write(Session("B")) %>
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Result of **SessionRedirect2.aspx** after Response.Redirect:

> A:
>
> B:

I turned trace on and still note that session values are lost when redirected to the 2nd page.

```
<%@ Page Trace="true" %>
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: I dug around and found some information for IIS, but not IIS Express on Microsoft TechNet: Worker process recycling drops application session state - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781036(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

change the AutoEventWireup="false" to AutoEventWireup="true" on the top of both pages